# Android intent data return null

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starter at Android and now I want to transfer data using intent from one activity to another.
First activity will collect datas and give it to second. but on second the data returns null. So have some errors on there. Here are my code.

```
public void previewStack(final Context context, final CreateStackNewActivity createStackNewActivity, final Stack stackDetails) {

        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if(stackDetails.getStackId() != -1){
            options.put("stack_id", String.valueOf(stackDetails.getStackId()));
        }

        int index = 1;

        for(StackLineNew stackLine : stackDetails.getLines()){
            options.put("title" + index, stackLine.getTitle());
            options.put("line_type" + index, Integer.toString(stackLine.getLineType().intValue));
            options.put("title" + index, stackLine.getTitle());
            if (stackLine.getBody().indexOf("file:/") == -1 && stackLine.getBody().indexOf("content:") == -1) {
                options.put("description" + index, stackLine.getBody());
                if (stackLine.getLineId() != -1) {
                    options.put("line_id" + index, Integer.toString(stackLine.getLineId()));
                }
            }
            index++;
        }

        Call<GenericAPIResponse> call = Hype4DAPI.previewStack(stackDetails.getName(), stackDetails.getCategory(), Integer.toString(stackDetails.getLines().size()), options, "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GenericAPIResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GenericAPIResponse> call, Response<GenericAPIResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    GenericAPIResponse saveStackResponse = response.body();
                    System.out.println(saveStackResponse);
                    Toast.makeText(context, saveStackResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    createStackNewActivity.saveInProgress = false;
                    createStackNewActivity.somethingHasChanged = false;
                    createStackNewActivity.updatePostButtonState();

                    Intent itnt = new Intent(createStackNewActivity, StackDetailsPage.class);
                    itnt.putExtra("stackId", stackDetails.getStackId());
                    itnt.putExtra("isPreview", "true");
                    itnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    createStackNewActivity.startActivity(itnt);



                } else {
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody());
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GenericAPIResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

And the code of second activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stack_details);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String stackId;
        if (intent != null) { //Null Checking
            stackId = intent.getStringExtra("stackId");
            isPreview = intent.getStringExtra("isPreview");
            stackTitleStr = intent.getStringExtra("stackTitle");
            saveLine = (HashMap<String, Object>)intent.getSerializableExtra("saveLine");
        }
        else{
            stackId = null;
        }
```

On second activity, I have all variables are null. isPreview, stackTitleStr, saveLine are all null.
So anyone please help me quickly.

Comment: in first activity try changing line "putExtra" to "putStringExtra".

Comment: first you should not create the intent in the onResponse callBack method but create a static method in your StackDetailsPage activity that return the intent it needs. With that this activity "said" to the other ones whats it needs, and you avoid duplicate string extra keys. use this : public static Intent getIntent(Context context, String stackId, String...) { Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackDetailsPage.class); intent.putExtra("stackId", stackId); ... return intent; }. and then in onResponse method do that : startActivity(StackDetailsPage.getIntent(context,getStackId(), ...))

Comment: remove `final`.just declare `Intent intent`

Comment: There is no "putStringExtra" method

Comment: Hi SebastienRieu, can you leave your anwser here in more details?

Answer (score 0):

first you should not create the intent in the onResponse callBack method but create a static method in your StackDetailsPage activity that return the intent it needs. With that, this activity "said" to the other ones whats it needs, and it avoid duplicate string extra keys. use this :

```
//in StackDetailsPage activity
public static Intent getIntent(Context context, String stackId, String...) 
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackDetailsPage.class); 
    intent.putExtra("stackId", stackId);
     ... 
    return intent; 
}
```

and then in onResponse method do that :

`startActivity(StackDetailsPage.getIntent(context,stackDetails.getStackId(), ...))`

Comment: Hi Sebastien, But why I have to declare getintent() function??? without declaration how it works now?

Comment: it's just an advice it's not mandatory but it improves the readability first and avoids duplicate code